# ActiveRecord count analysis in rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am hardly checking to find the execution speed of two queries, explain analyze and benchmark because i got timeout for one query but i am not sure this query was causing this.

```
queue_count = purchase.purchase_items.where("queue_id = ?", queue.id).count
```

same sql query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "purchase_items" WHERE "purchase_items"."purchase_id" = 1241422 AND (queue_id = 3479783)
```

so i have to remove the count then i got one solution to take all record in array and do the count then i got the query like this

```
queue_count = purchase.purchase_items.where("queue_id = ?", queue.id).all.count
```

same sql query

```
SELECT "purchase_items".* FROM "purchase_items" WHERE "purchase_items"."purchase_id" = 1241422 AND (queue_id = 3479783)
```

finally got some slight variation when i was checking with query analyze and also benchmark, so this was the correct way? or am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance second query will be quite terrible. It will load **all** records in memory and count them using Ruby. Database is designed to do stuff like this quickly.

In order to analyze query you can do `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in Psql console. My long shot is that you're missing some indexes (on purchase_id and queue_id). You can look into this by running:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchase_items WHERE purchase_id = 1241422 AND (queue_id = 3479783)
```

If you see that PostgreSQL is scanning whole table, then performance will not be optimal. Try adding indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX  purchase_id_purchase_items_idx ON purchase_items (purchase_id);
CREATE INDEX  queue_id_purchase_items_idx ON purchase_items (queue_id);
```

and examining performance using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` then. But **never** load all records into Ruby to do simple `.count` on them.

Comment: I already have that index, but one more thing  when i do analyze EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchase_items WHERE purchase_id = 1241422 AND (queue_id = 3479783) this query in first hit this shows Execution time: 1.088 ms, second hit this shows 0.148 ms, is there any logic behind to check one more times or the first hit execution time is correct?

Comment: you need to run it few times and calculate f.e. average - one try isn't enough to get correct data. And if it's 1 ms or 0.1 ms then it's really fast and definitely not a bottleneck